# Setting CWDir as a variable for MS-Dos environment

Tags: python

Can someone help me with this please?
I am trying to compile a program in this case programmed in python that I can run in win9Xdos, that I can call/start from a 9xDos batchfile, that will find the Current working Dir & by that I mean identify the cwd (current working directory) from where the python program and batchfile are executed. The python program will be called getcwd.py which I am hoping someone will outline what I need to do to convert to EXE/COM file. there is a program called Py2EXE but not sure if this will compile for Ms-dos file. Anyways heres my simple code thus far. Can someone tell me if I am on the right track please? Oh by the way what I am trying to do is find the CWD & inject the resultant path into a variable that can be read from 9Xdos. The current Var would be %cwd%

```
# importing os module
import os

# some websites say use: del cwd (to remove variable if it exists)
cwd = none
cwd = os.getcwd()
print(cwd)
```

The print line may need interchanging with code below, not sure help needed:

```
print(type(path))
# <class 'str'>
```

would the above code work, say in the root e.g. C:\ with & work in obtaining the CWD variable & if correct how would I proceed to compile it to an exe/com file? do I need to take into account LFN's & Spaces between possible paths e.g C:\Program Files & possible backslashes etc?

Comment: `py2exe` was a casualty of the migration from Python 2 to Python 3 and has not been supported since around 3.3. Look at `pyinstaller` as a more up-to-date alternative to produce an `.exe` file. There is not and I think never has been a way to create a `.com` file from Python code. But I don't understand why you want to use Python at all. The value you want is already available in a batch file using `%cd%`.

Comment: @Boargules - %CD% variable does not work in Win9XDos I have tried that there is a Dos workaround but that is messy. Can you tell me if the Python code is good or not I will need to edit as I should have put some code that would clear any Current Var before running the program apologies extended. Thanks for the info re Py2exe And pyinstaller for exe's Thanks!

Comment: You should basically almost never need `os.getcwd()`; the pseudo-directory `"."` already refers to the invoking user's current working directory.

Comment: Your code has obvious capitalization problems; could you please [edit] to fix those?

Comment: @ tripleee sorry removed caps from code, in respect of os.getcwd( ) do I just replace os.getcwd( ) with "." if yes I will edit accordingly

Comment: Your Python code looks okay but wrapping it into an .exe will be a major hassle. The appropriate version of Python for your OS is 1.5.2 and you will find it hard to locate an interpreter, let alone tools like py2exe.

Comment: @Boargules I have managed to acquire a copy of python 1.5.2 & py2exe. What interpreter would I need I will try to locate. Could you outline the steps required to compile. Just guessing here but are there any online compilers that would suffice? I have these so far Py152.exe for windows, py2exe-0.6.9.win32-py2.7.exe

Comment: You already have Python 1.5.2. That is the interpreter. You will have to follow the docs for `py2exe`: I remember little about it because I haven't used it for years: it went obsolete long ago. You can't actually *compile* Python. What `py2exe` does is wrap up the bytecode of your program and any modules it imports and all the DLLs they import, together with a copy of `python.exe`, into one enormous executable that can take ages to load.

Comment: @ BoarGules - When you say enormous as an estimation how big? sounds as if this could be self defeating, with ages to load, does not sound good?

Comment: I don't even know if `py2exe` works with Python 1.5.2. The first release of `py2exe`was in 2003 and Python 1.5.2 was already 3 years obsolete by then.

Comment: @ All - Seasons greetings MERRY CHRISTMAS & A HAPPY NEW YEAR!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't perfect but it is on the right track. All you need is this:

```
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(os.getcwd())
```

There is no need for an auxiliary variable, and I don't know what websites are recommending that you delete the variable before creating it. Trying to delete a nonexistent Python variable is a runtime error. So I would stay away from those websites.

But your question is about setting an environment variable. Calling `print()` won't do that. All it will do is echo the current working directory to the console. There is no way to change the environment of a running process that will affect the parent process. This is not a Python restriction nor a Windows restriction: it is quite general. The OS sets up the environment of the process when it creates the process. You can make changes to the environment (using `os.environ[env-var]`) but those changes will only be visible inside that Python process and will not be visible to the environment of the batch file that runs the Python program. To do that, you need to pass the value back to the calling process.

One way to do that is like this:

In Python:

```
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f"set CWDIR={os.getcwd()}", file=open("mycd.bat","w"))
```

I haven't had a Python 1.5.2 environment for 15 years, so I can't test this, but I think the equivalent would have been

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print >> open("mycd.bat","w"), "set CWDIR=%s" % (os.getcwd(),)
```

In a `cmd.exe` console:

```
call mycd.bat
```

Though if your Win9XDos doesn't provide `%cd%` (which, as far as I recall, was available in MS-DOS 5, or maybe further back still) there is no way of telling if it supports `call` either. (Are you maybe running `command.com` instead of `cmd.exe`? That would explain why things that should be there are missing).

I used `pyinstaller` to create a 64-bit `.exe` and that resulted in a file of about 6MB. Now, 32-bit executables are smaller, but it might be that the resulting executable is still too big to load.

So I think the Python route may turn out to be more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: I think you are right! please excuse my ignorance, in such matters I thought/was hoping it would be relatively easy to write the code & compile it. I'm afraid I was wrong however can I take this oppertunity to thank everyone for their help & guidance, it is appreciated & I am sorry that I led everyone down the garden path. Best wishes David